# openwrt luci uhttpd permission denied

Tags: router, openwrt, firmware, luci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfnMS.jpg)

How do I get Permission to Start and Enable /etc/init.d/uhttpd ??

Router: TP Link WR-940N v3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this kind of scripts needs a parameter like `start`, `stop`, `reload`... Have you tried? Does the `/etc/init.d/uhttpd` have execution rights?